# Deflationary after sharding?

Tags: gas

I understand that the deflationary part of Ethereum happens if the gas fee is higher than X, then it becomes deflationary (total supply will go down, according to https://ultrasound.money, if the gas is > 15 gwei)

My question is: if sharding solves the high gas problem, does it mean that after sharding, the gas fee will be very low and Ethereum will not become deflationary anymore? Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Sharding does not necessarily solve the problem of high gas fees, but theoretically lowers the network congestion and increases the transaction speed. Gas fee is also influenced by the price of ETH and the number of transactions being processed on the network, which varies based on the demand of ETH. If the price and demand of ETH increase, the gas fee can also increase and if it increases to higher than X (based on current stake rate), Ethereum can become deflationary and its total supply can go down. Hence, it does not mean that after sharding, the gas fee will be very low and Ethereum will not become deflationary anymore.